# "Error while linking" while compiling empty project using Lazarus (fpc) 32bit on debian-based Linux

Tags: linker-errors, 32-bit, freepascal, lazarus, debian-based

I have old 32bit laptop working under MX Linux (v.20230709, 32bit) on which I installed latest Lazarus (i386, v.3.2.2) along with fpc i386, v.3.2.2.

When I create a new empty project of Application type and hit "Run", I expect to see an empty form with no error messages, but I have error messages instead:

```
Compile Project, Target: /home/lum/tmp/project1: Exit code 1, Errors: 2, Warnings: 2
Warning: linker: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/fpc/3.2.2/units/i386-linux/rtl/si_c21.o: in function `SI_C21_$$__FPC_LIBC21_START':
Error: si_c21.pp:(.text.n_si_c21_$$__fpc_libc21_start+0x27): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
Warning: linker: /usr/bin/ld: si_c21.pp:(.text.n_si_c21_$$__fpc_libc21_start+0x2c): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
project1.lpr(24,1) Error: Error while linking
```

Tried to find a solution, but google showed a few pages discussing the subject with no solution to the problem. Seems like 32bit is really deprecated now...

Can anyone suggest a step-by-step solution so Lazarus can function on old 32bit hardware?